# How to test the content of callback of method

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I might not be getting something but I am trying to test the callback content of a method but without calling the method.

The function I am trying to test

```
functionToSkip(param1, param2, function(arg1, arg2){
    if(arg1){
        // Do some things here
    } else {
        // Do other things here
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to test the content of the callback function with differents args values that I can change in the tests and the parameter of the functionToSkip can be anything.

All I successfully did is to skip the call of the function but I cannot call the callback method.

I did stub the function to skip and even trying to give values to the callback method but there is not any logs showing.

```
var spy = sinon.stub(Class, "functionToSkip").calledWith(param1, param2, ("arg1","arg2"))
```

The main method that is calling the stubbed function works since I can see the logs prior of the function when I call it in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if `functionToSkip` is an instance method on `Class`, it will be a property on `Class.prototype`, not `Class` itself. In order to stub, you can do one of two things:

Create an instance, and create the stub:

```
instance = new Class(/*costructor arguments*/)
var stub = sinon.stub(instance, 'functionToSkip')
```

Or, stub on the prototype:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(Class.prototype, 'functionToSkip');
```

In the second case, since class prototypes are global state, I'd recommend restoring it-- preferably in something like mocha `afterEach` to ensure it gets cleaned up whether your test is successful or not. This way it doesn't screw with other tests in your run:

```
stub.restore()
```

Between the two, though, I recommend the first approach.

Next up... If you want to make assertions on the content of calls, the firs thing you'll probably want to do is assert that it was in fact called with the signature you're looking for:

```
sinon.assert.calledWith(stub, sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any, sinon.match.func)
```

The `any` matcher allows any value, and the `func` matcher requires a func. After that, you can obtain the callback function like so:

```
var cb = stub.firstCall.args[2]
```

And invoke it like so:

```
cb('arg1', 'arg2');
```

As to what assertions you'd do after invoking the callback function-- I'd have to know more about what you're trying to test about it to make recommendations.